# Excel Row or Column Variable

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I'm trying to use excel to calculate a new price for a large number of different types of products by a set percentage.

I have the old price of the products in column B in the spreadsheet, and wish to display the new price in column C.  I know that the formula I need to set in column C for, for example, row 2 would be =B2 * 1.04, if I wanted to increase the price by 4%.

However, I believe it would be easier to expedite this process if there was some function I could replace 2 in B2 with a variable that would indicate the current row, so that I could write one function for all rows.

Is there any variable like this that I can use in excel functions?

Comment: When you refer to "writing a function", do you mean a VBA function or a formula? If a formula, will filling down (and therefore having B2 automatically change to B3 when copied into cell B3) not work?

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want is already a function of MS Excel. Upon pasting the formula = B2 * 1.04 in cell C3, C4 .... C-n what excel does is updates the formula to B3 * 1.04, B4 * 1.04 .... B-n * 1.04 respectively. All you have to do copy paste your formula from C2 down to all the rows that you want to calculate the % of.

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple.

Put the number 2 in cell d1

then type in c1 =b1*$d$1

or you can type in c1 =b1*d1(then press f4 to get $)

you just copy the number in all the rows and change value in d1